# Design on irregular domain

Tags: experiment-design, model, latin-hypercube

I am trying to get a design over some input parameters for a computer model, saying an input vector $X=(X_1,...,X_k)$. The domain of $X$ is irregular, not a hypercube (so I guess conventional Latin Hypercube design is not available).

I want to get a kind of space-filling design, if anyone can help me with this problem? Many thanks!

Comment: Sphere-packing designs might be what you're looking for. These links from SAS might be of interest to you: http://www.jmp.com/support/help/Sphere-Packing_Designs.shtml http://www.jmp.com/support/help/Space-Filling_Designs.shtml

Comment: You could also look at algorithmic design: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65967/good-useful-and-characteristic-experiments-for-optimal-statistical-design-of